# Не могу исправить ошибку CS0246 в Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Не могу исправить ошибку: "`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'player_Control' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`". Кто-нибудь знает, как это исправить?

Файл `Cont_Button.cs`:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cont_Button : MonoBehaviour {
    private player_Control player;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        player = FindObjectOfType<player_Control> ();
    }
    public void LeftArrow(){
        player.moveright = false;
        player.moveleft = true;
        Debug.Log ("MoveLeft");
    }
    public void RightArrow(){
        player.moveright = true;
        player.moveleft = false;
        Debug.Log ("MoveRight");
    }
    public void ReleaseLeftArrow(){
        player.moveleft = false;
    }
    public void ReleaseRightArrow(){
        player.moveright = false;
    }
    public void Jump(){
        player.jump = true;
        debug.Log ("Jump");
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        
    }
}
```

Я также пытался добавить строку `using <player_Control namespace>;` в начало, но это не помогло.

Comment: player_Control нужно импортировать(using) или создать

Comment: как это сделать как ослу обьясните

Comment: сначала изучаем c# и только потом unity, это самая простая ошибка, по сути ошибка уже ответила что нужно сделать

Comment: А вы обьяснить можете по проще ? Если я сюда написал значит я чего то не понимаю и было бы не плохо дать ответ на вопрос по простому а не рассказывать мне что это самая простая ошибка

Comment: Вставьте код текстом.

Comment: `не плохо дать ответ на вопрос` - Понимаете в чем дело... Во первых, это база знаний, которая собирает ценные вопросы для удобного и быстрого их поиска, ответьте на простейший вопрос - **есть ли в вашем вопросе хоть доля ценности для сообщества** и будущих читателей, или это мусор? Я считаю, что ценности ноль. Во вторых, если вы не знаете банальных основ, у вас нету самого минимального уровня, то даже если мы дадим ответ, вы его не поймете (как это видно сейчас, где вам дали четко что делать, а вы не думая скопировали текст). Так что **полезно-ли это для вас с таким уровнем знаний** сейчас?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте вверху файла пространство имен (namespace), где определен тип `player_Control`:

```
using <player_Control namespace>;
```

Comment: "пространство имен  не может напрямую включать в себя такие члены как поля или методы"

Comment: @ОлександрКлючицький Что это значит? Где объявлен тип `player_Control`?

Comment: @ОлександрКлючицький А-а-а, увидел новую картинку. Вместо "<player_Control namespace>" нужно написать название пространства имен, в котором определен тип `player_Control`.

Comment: по конкретнее можете ? если не сложно что где и как а лучше скриншотом если вам не трудно

Comment: @ОлександрКлючицький Я не могу сделать скриншот кода, которого у меня. Не говоря уже о том, что это не поощряется правилами сайта. Мы с Вами не продвинемся в решении Вашей задачи, если Вы будете игнорировать мои вопросы. Где объявлен тип `player_Control`?